# How to fix CSS jumpy transition animation?

Tags: css

I've a `styled-component` as below:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: ${props => (props.show ? "1" : "0")};
  height: ${props => (props.show ? "100%" : "0")};
  padding: ${props => (props.show ? "15px 0px" : "0 15px")};
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;

  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
`;
```

It's working fine with `prop` 'show'. The issue is the 'Wrapper' `div` is at the top. And all other elements are below 'Wrapper'. When 'show' becomes `false`, the `transition ease-out` works. But when animation completes, the element below 'Wrapper' jumps on top and takes the available space.

I tried with attributes `height` and `max-height` instead of `all` in `transition` but got the same result.

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-sun-bi11c)

**How do I fix that elements below Wrapper smoothly go on top in co-ordination with `ease-out` ?**

Comment: Please post your rendered HTML and CSS. As it is now, we don't know what your HTML structure looks like. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The problem is with the height `height: auto` I set it to `100px` and `fade-outh` is smooth.

Comment: @Grzegorz T. can you please fork and share sandbox url ?

Comment: @Valay There is no need to do the next sandbox, change `height: $ {props => (props.show? "100%": "0")};` for this `height: $ {props => (props.show? "100px": "0")};` The browser does not really know how much to shift if the value is auto or 100%. The solution is to either download the height after clicking and setting in the style-component or read this [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/) ;)